# How to print all thumbnail_url from the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python and trying to print all thumbnail_url from the data? in Python? The data is medias

the issue is its logging only one thumbnail_url but in the data their are multiple thumbnail_urls –

But i want to print al thumbnail_url from that data how to do that with my code?

```
from instagrapi import Client

cl = Client()

user_id = cl.user_id_from_username("taylorswift")
medias = cl.user_medias(user_id, 2)
print(medias)

for media in medias:
    print(media.thumbnail_url)
```

When i print medias i logs this:

```
[Media(pk='3166098261500503829', id='3166098261500503829_11830955', code='CvwPZgYuCcV', taken_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 10, 6, 19, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), media_type=1, image_versions2={}, product_type='', thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/366422100_147674528370406_9143482148277133418_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=cdW2KRgKhFwAX_q213Y&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfDN_8KdH9W8IkKQctB-YuU2PB8jTNBfiqPI3txQ3U68IA&oe=653B9F64&_nc_sid=bc0c2c', ), location=None, user=UserShort(pk='11830955', username='taylorswift', full_name='', profile_pic_url=None, profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=None, stories=[]), comment_count=0, comments_disabled=False, commenting_disabled_for_viewer=False, like_count=12103691, play_count=None, has_liked=None, caption_text='Surprise!! 1989 (Taylor’s Version) is on its way to you ! The 1989 album changed my life in countless ways, and it fills me with such excitement to announce that my version of it will be out October 27th. To be perfectly honest, this is my most FAVORITE re-record I’ve ever done because the 5 From The Vault tracks are so insane. I can’t believe they were ever left behind. But not for long! Pre order 1989 (Taylor’s Version) on my site \n\n: @bethgarrabrant', accessibility_caption=None, usertags=[Usertag(user=UserShort(pk='34234869', username='bethgarrabrant', full_name='', profile_pic_url=None, profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=None, stories=[]), x=0.1084444444, y=0.9653333333)], sponsor_tags=[], video_url=None, view_count=0, video_duration=0.0, title='', resources=[], clips_metadata={}), Media(pk='3216661270631227092', id='3216661270631227092_11830955', code='Cyj4GIOux7U', taken_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 19, 0, 38, 46, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), media_type=8, image_versions2={}, product_type='', thumbnail_url=None, location=None, user=UserShort(pk='11830955', username='taylorswift', full_name='', profile_pic_url=None, profile_pic_url_hd=None, is_private=None, stories=[]), comment_count=0, comments_disabled=False, commenting_disabled_for_viewer=False, like_count=8958347, play_count=None, has_liked=None, caption_text='What a truly mind blowing thing you’ve turned The Eras Tour Concert Film into. I’ve been watching videos of you guys in the theaters dancing and prancing and recreating choreography, creating inside jokes, casting spells, getting engaged, and just generally creating the exact type of joyful chaos we’re known for  One of my favorite things you’ve done was when you supported Cruel Summer SO much, I ended up starting The Eras Tour show with it. For old times sake, I’m releasing the live audio from the tour so we can all shriek it in the comfort of our homes and cars PLUS a brand new remix by @lpgiobbi  Thank you, so much, forever, wow, just thank you!!!', accessibility_caption=None, usertags=[], sponsor_tags=[], video_url=None, view_count=0, video_duration=0.0, title='', resources=[Resource(pk='3216661266730456068', video_url=None, thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/393317010_188736784271768_181787686406934824_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Mf-BegeGDaEAX9Om1it&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCwfa3eSMrNLadCAHXVYTI1G4S0IqbeNdBnQE8LjUqNpQ&oe=653B8EFC&_nc_sid=bc0c2c', ), media_type=1), Resource(pk='3216661266713656181', video_url=None, thumbnail_url=HttpUrl('https://instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/392900218_3509080919308926_3206171248972258297_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Z7G6afnlzV4AX_LBdD7&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCw4dIzWnrTtSLG6WLY1Ms86H5_oSYZftA23wk8Hva5bQ&oe=653B894C&_nc_sid=bc0c2c', ), media_type=1)], clips_metadata={})]
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have?

Comment: its logging only one thumbnail_url but in the data their are multiple thumbnail_urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your data is nested, as seen if you format your `Medias` object:

```py
    [
    Media(
        pk="3166098261500503829",
        id="3166098261500503829_11830955",
        code="CvwPZgYuCcV",
        taken_at=datetime.datetime(2023, 8, 10, 6, 19, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
        media_type=1,
        image_versions2={},
        product_type="",
        thumbnail_url=HttpUrl(
            "https://instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/366422100_147674528370406_9143482148277133418_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=cdW2KRgKhFwAX_q213Y&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfDN_8KdH9W8IkKQctB-YuU2PB8jTNBfiqPI3txQ3U68IA&oe=653B9F64&_nc_sid=bc0c2c",
        ),
        location=None,
        user=UserShort(
            pk="11830955",
            username="taylorswift",
            full_name="",
            profile_pic_url=None,
            profile_pic_url_hd=None,
            is_private=None,
            stories=[],
        ),
        comment_count=0,
        comments_disabled=False,
        commenting_disabled_for_viewer=False,
        like_count=12103691,
        play_count=None,
        has_liked=None,
        caption_text="Surprise!! 1989 (Taylor’s Version) is on its way to you ! The 1989 album changed my life in countless ways, and it fills me with such excitement to announce that my version of it will be out October 27th. To be perfectly honest, this is my most FAVORITE re-record I’ve ever done because the 5 From The Vault tracks are so insane. I can’t believe they were ever left behind. But not for long! Pre order 1989 (Taylor’s Version) on my site \n\n: @bethgarrabrant",
        accessibility_caption=None,
        usertags=[
            Usertag(
                user=UserShort(
                    pk="34234869",
                    username="bethgarrabrant",
                    full_name="",
                    profile_pic_url=None,
                    profile_pic_url_hd=None,
                    is_private=None,
                    stories=[],
                ),
                x=0.1084444444,
                y=0.9653333333,
            )
        ],
        sponsor_tags=[],
        video_url=None,
        view_count=0,
        video_duration=0.0,
        title="",
        resources=[],
        clips_metadata={},
    ),
    Media(
        pk="3216661270631227092",
        id="3216661270631227092_11830955",
        code="Cyj4GIOux7U",
        taken_at=datetime.datetime(
            2023, 10, 19, 0, 38, 46, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc
        ),
        media_type=8,
        image_versions2={},
        product_type="",
        thumbnail_url=None,
        location=None,
        user=UserShort(
            pk="11830955",
            username="taylorswift",
            full_name="",
            profile_pic_url=None,
            profile_pic_url_hd=None,
            is_private=None,
            stories=[],
        ),
        comment_count=0,
        comments_disabled=False,
        commenting_disabled_for_viewer=False,
        like_count=8958347,
        play_count=None,
        has_liked=None,
        caption_text="What a truly mind blowing thing you’ve turned The Eras Tour Concert Film into. I’ve been watching videos of you guys in the theaters dancing and prancing and recreating choreography, creating inside jokes, casting spells, getting engaged, and just generally creating the exact type of joyful chaos we’re known for  One of my favorite things you’ve done was when you supported Cruel Summer SO much, I ended up starting The Eras Tour show with it. For old times sake, I’m releasing the live audio from the tour so we can all shriek it in the comfort of our homes and cars PLUS a brand new remix by @lpgiobbi  Thank you, so much, forever, wow, just thank you!!!",
        accessibility_caption=None,
        usertags=[],
        sponsor_tags=[],
        video_url=None,
        view_count=0,
        video_duration=0.0,
        title="",
        resources=[
            Resource(
                pk="3216661266730456068",
                video_url=None,
                thumbnail_url=HttpUrl(
                    "https://instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/393317010_188736784271768_181787686406934824_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Mf-BegeGDaEAX9Om1it&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCwfa3eSMrNLadCAHXVYTI1G4S0IqbeNdBnQE8LjUqNpQ&oe=653B8EFC&_nc_sid=bc0c2c",
                ),
                media_type=1,
            ),
            Resource(
                pk="3216661266713656181",
                video_url=None,
                thumbnail_url=HttpUrl(
                    "https://instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/392900218_3509080919308926_3206171248972258297_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s1080x1080&_nc_ht=instagram.flko10-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=Z7G6afnlzV4AX_LBdD7&edm=APU89FABAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCw4dIzWnrTtSLG6WLY1Ms86H5_oSYZftA23wk8Hva5bQ&oe=653B894C&_nc_sid=bc0c2c",
                ),
                media_type=1,
            ),
        ],
        clips_metadata={},
    ),
]
```

The second `thumbnail_url` is `None` and the other 4 are part of a `Resource` object in the `Resources` list.

so you'll have to add a second loop to check all the `Resource` objects for a `thumbnail_url` as well. something like the below should do the trick:

```py
for media in medias:
    print(media.thumbnail_url)
    for resource in media.resources:
        print(resource.thumbnail_url)
```